# copy string with offsett C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i need help to copy string with offset and invert 
how i implement this function ?

```
void copyString(char *input, int offset, int length, bool invert, char *output, int output_offset)
```

input : input string
offset : starting position to be copied.
length : length of substring of input to be copied.
invert : the result would be inverted if true.
output : result string.
output_offset : starting position of output to receive the copied string
example

```
st ="Hello World";
st2="My Name is Fatima";
copyString(st,6,5,true,st2,11) -> st2 = "My Name is dlrow";
```

i have succes with copystring function without offset and invert..
this my function

```
void stringcpy(const char* src,char* dest)
{

while(*src != '\0')
 {
    *dest++ = *src++;    
 }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 const char str[] = "fatima";
char str2[sizeof(str)] ;

const char* s  = str;
char* s2 = str2;

stringcpy(s, s2);
cout<<str2<<"\n";
cout<<str<<"\n";

system("pause");
```

}

anyone can help ?

Comment: Start by adding one little piece of functionality (like e.g. the source string offset). Then after you have made sure it works, you add the next little piece. And so on until you have it working as is required.

Comment: You are forgetting to copy the null character

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need the pointer variables `s` and `s2`. When you pass an array (like `str`) as argument it will decay to a pointer to its first element, just what is happening with the assignment.